# Finding a third degree polynomial that passes through given points

Tags: interpolation, polynomials

If I have three points xi-1,xi, xi+1 where y(xi) =1 and y(xi-1)=0, y(xi+1)=0 (basis function) and I need to define a line that passes through these points I will use the line equation y-y1=(y2-y1) /(x2-x1) *(x-x1) first trough points (xi-1,xi) and then trough points (xi, xi+1).

---

My question is how can I define a third degree polynomial (or even higher) trough these three points??

Comment: Look up `InterpolatingPolynomial[]`.

Comment: Or look up [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: Lagrange works with simple y=ax+b functions. Now I need Hermite but it's not working when I use HermiteH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your specified points are

```
pts = {{xi - 1, 0}, {xi, 1}, {xi + 1, 0}};
```

[`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) finds the lowest degree polynomial fitting the points. For three points this is a second degree polynomial.

```
f[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x]

(* (1 + x - xi) (1 - x + xi) *)
```

To find a higher degree polynomial add additional points at arbitrary unique locations.

```
poly[degree_Integer?(# > 1 &)][x_] :=
 InterpolatingPolynomial[
   Join[pts, {xa[#], ya[#]} & /@ Range[degree - 2]], x] //
  FullSimplify
```

Verifying that `poly` of degree 2 is identical to `f`

```
f[x] === poly[2][x]

(* True *)
```

The third degree polynomial is

```
poly[3][x]

(* (1 + x - xi) (1 + (x - 
      xi) (-1 + ((-1 + x - xi) (1 + (
         1 + ya[1]/(-1 - xi + xa[1]))/(-xi + xa[1])))/(1 - xi + xa[1]))) *)
```

Verifying that this polynomial passes through the original points

```
pts === ({#, poly[3][#]} & /@ {xi - 1, xi, xi + 1})

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried with this approach and it worked but I am having trouble plotting the function when the interval is [0,1]. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't work with plot[poly[3][x],{x,0,1}] ?

Comment: Did you assign values to xi, xa[1], and ya[1]?

Comment: No, I need it to work with any arbitrary interval [xi, xi+1] or [xi-1,xi]. Do I have to assign them? I don't really know any values except that it's 1 at xi and 0 at xi-1 and xi+1

Comment: You must assign values to plot.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks again, you've really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The associated coefficients for a k-th degree polynomial to fit through `{{xi-1,0},{xi,1},{xi+1,0}}` can be found through `Solve` (better for `k=2`) and `Reduce` (for `k=3` and `k=4`).  While I'm I don't understand the desire for doing this for `k=3` and `k=4`, I certainly wouldn't recommend do this for `k > 4`.

```
(* Quadratic *)
Solve[{a[0] + a[1] xi + a[2] xi^2 == 1,
  a[0] + a[1] (xi - 1) + a[2] (xi - 1)^2 == 0,
  a[0] + a[1] (xi + 1) + a[2] (xi + 1)^2 == 0},
 {a[0], a[1], a[2]}]
(* {{a[0] -> 1-xi^2,a[1] -> 2 xi,a[2] -> -1}} *)

(* Cubic *)
Reduce[{a[0] + a[1] xi + a[2] xi^2 + a[3] xi^3 == 1,
  a[0] + a[1] (xi - 1) + a[2] (xi - 1)^2 + a[3] (xi - 1)^3 == 0,
  a[0] + a[1] (xi + 1) + a[2] (xi + 1)^2 + a[3] (xi + 1)^3 == 0},
 {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]}]
```

[image: Coefficients for k=3]

```
(* Quartic *)
k = 4
Reduce[{Sum[a[i] xi^i, {i, 0, k}] == 1,
  Sum[a[i] (xi - 1)^i, {i, 0, k}] == 0,
  Sum[a[i] (xi + 1)^i, {i, 0, k}] == 0}, Table[a[i], {i, 0, k}]]
```

[image: Coefficients for k=4]

Comment: I don't really need the coefficients, I need to define basis functions w and z that are constructed of Hermite basis interpolation polynomials so I can get a third degree polynomial v with which I am approximating a solution u of PDE of 4th order (precisely the elliptic PDE of fourth order with Dirichlet and Neumanns boundary conditions). I tried using HermiteH but it's not really doing the job so I'm trying out different methods. When it was a PDE of first order I just used the line equation formula and it was easy.

Comment: OK.  Next time you should add such information to your question.  You'll get more targeted answers.